# Update certain columns based on date. Best way to approach this issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table I need to update. In this table there is a column for each month. If someone's start date is 2/13/2015 I need to update the February column with some data from a calculation.

So if Start_Date is 2/17/2015 then the value for the February column called FTEFeb needs to be populated.  If the Start_Date is 3/09/2015 then the FTEMar column needs to be updated etc...

I was thinking a CASE statment would work but the SET column would be different based on the value in Start Date.

I've looked online for anything similar and nothing came up.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why case is not working? Please elaborate.

Comment: Some sample data, and expected result, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement.

For your query, instead of preforming a CASE on the month, just write a case to update each column, and if the column is not the month you want you can set it to 0, or whatever your business rule is. Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET 
  FTEJan = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEFeb = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEMar = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEApr = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEMay = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEJun = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEJul = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEAug = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTESep = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEOct = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTENov = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  FTEDec = (CASE WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7813a/1) example.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for this and creating the SQL example so I can see exactly how the code works!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3119773 glad I could help. If this remains the solution you use, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers know what solved your problem.